# Any advice for my callable class decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm currently learning Python and i started digging decorators !

So basically i wanted to create a decorator (especially a callable class !) that could be used in both scenarios:

Case 1 :

```
@Decorator
def foo():
    return True
```

Case 2 :

```
@Decorator(bar=2)
def foo():
    return True
```

I'd like to use it with optional arguments and avoiding trailing parenthesis like this :

```
@Decorator()
def foo():
    return True
```

So here's what i got about it (i gave it a shot with only my knowledge of decorators as functions):

```
class Decorator:
    func: Callable  # The decorated function
    bar: int

    def __init__(self, func: Callable = None, bar: int = 0):
        self.func = func
        # Decorator called without argument : func is not None (case 1)
        # Decorator called with arguments : func is None (case 2)
        self.bar = bar

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.func is None:
            # Decorator called with arguments (case 2)
            # The first arg must be the decorated function
            if not args or not (callable(args[0])):
                raise TypeError('First argument must be a callable')

            self.func = args[0]
            return self.wrapped
        else:
            # Decorator called without argument (case 1)
            return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        # Encapsulating the decorated function's call
        # Do some stuff
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works as intended (definitely a win as far as my learning is concerned), but I'm still looking for improvement/advice (maybe there's a much better way to achieve this, or this specific case isn't used at all, is it ?).

Bonus question : how to add **functools.wraps** in this decorator, i read the documentation about **functools.update_wrapper(self, func)** but this won't work with my **wrapped** function, right ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question (probably) belongs on codereview.

Comment: @baduker The code above appears to be [stripped of context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1710/120114)  and thus would be off-topic on CR. In the future, please don't use the existence of the CR site as a reason to close a question. Use a reason like *needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Also see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)